# How to use render props in React to expose information about a component's state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, headless-ui

I have read about render props extensively on the official React documentation as well as other articles. However, I am trying to do something similar to what Tailwind does and am failing to figure out how they use this pattern in their components to expose state information about a component.

For example, if you have a look at their [Switch](https://headlessui.com/react/switch) component. Its usage is as follows:

```
function MyToggle() {
  const [enabled, setEnabled] = useState(false)

  return (
    <Switch checked={enabled} onChange={setEnabled} as={Fragment}>
      {({ checked }) => (
        /* Use the `checked` state to conditionally style the button. */
        <button
          className={`${
            checked ? 'bg-blue-600' : 'bg-gray-200'
          } relative inline-flex h-6 w-11 items-center rounded-full`}
        >
          <span className="sr-only">Enable notifications</span>
          <span
            className={`${
              checked ? 'translate-x-6' : 'translate-x-1'
            } inline-block h-4 w-4 transform rounded-full bg-white transition`}
          />
        </button>
      )}
    </Switch>
  )
}
```

If I were to write the Switch component from scratch, I would instantiate a state for `checked` in the component function but how do I make it so that the state is exposed when I use the component in the manner:

```
<Switch>
      {({ checked }) => (
        ...
      )}
</Switch>
```

From their [github](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/headlessui/blob/main/packages/%40headlessui-react/src/components/switch/switch.tsx),they do something like:

```
function SwitchFn(props) {
  let {
    checked,
    ...theirProps
  } = props

  let [checked, onChange] = useControllable(controlledChecked, controlledOnChange, defaultChecked)

  let slot = useMemo<SwitchRenderPropArg>(() => ({ checked }), [checked])
  ...
return (
    <>
      {name != null && checked && (
        <Hidden
          features={HiddenFeatures.Hidden}
          {...compact({
            as: 'input',
            type: 'checkbox',
            hidden: true,
            readOnly: true,
            form,
            checked,
            name,
            value,
          })}
        />
      )}
      {render({ ourProps, theirProps, slot, defaultTag: DEFAULT_SWITCH_TAG, name: 'Switch' })}
    </>
  )
}
```

But it is quite difficult to follow along. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to do

```
<Switch>
      {({ checked }) => (
        ...
      )}
</Switch>
```

It means that `children` is a callback instead of a React Node.

In the component implementation it means that instead of simply calling `children` that evaluates to a `Node`, you would call `children(...)`.
So you could implement Switch with something like

```
function Switch({children}){
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
  ...

  return (
    // it's of course more complex that that, but the core idea is here
    <div onClick={() => setChecked(current => !current)}> 
     {children({checked})}
    </div>
  );

}
```

It's a specific case of a render prop, where the prop is [`children`](https://react.dev/learn/passing-props-to-a-component#passing-jsx-as-children).

### Note

You could ask "But where is children actually called in that Tailwind code???"

`switch.tsx` uses `utils/render.ts` which [extracts children from the props](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/headlessui/blob/01a34cb0c48329b478dea28fef391c71cee57550/packages/%40headlessui-react/src/utils/render.ts#L130C60-L130C60).

Comment: Thanks for the help! This made it all clear and led me down the path of the Function as a Child pattern which, I suppose is what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Lets start with a perhaps simpler example, courtesy of [Steven Wittens](https://acko.net/blog/model-view-catharsis/):

```
<ValidatingInput
  parse={parseNumber} format={formatNumber}
  value={number}    setValue={setNumber}
>{
  (value, isError, onChange, onBlur) =>
    <TextField
      value={value}      isError={isError}
      onChange={onChange} onBlur={onBlur} />
}</ValidatingInput>
```

Here we *wrap the text field* to modify the default behavior. Note that it doesn't have to be a `TextField`, and the value doesn't have to be a number, that's up to the *user* of `ValidatingInput`.

The important bit is that we ask the user of `ValidatingInput` to provide us with some stuff: the current state, a setter for that state, a parser to parse the input from the end user, and a formatter to show what gets displayed to the user in the input field.

Then we *provide* the render prop function with the other half of the glue for wiring up to the DOM to respond to events. The definition of `ValidatingInput` could look something like this:

```
const ValidatingInput = ({
  value,
  setValue,
  parse = x => x,
  format = x => x,
  children: render,
}) => {
  const [internalValue, setInternalValue] = useState(value);
  const [isError, setError] = useState();
  const onChange = useCallback((evt) => {
    setInternalValue(evt.target.value);
  }, []);

  const onBlur = useCallback(() => {
    try {
      setValue(parse(internalValue));
      // clear any error state after successful parse
      setError();
    } catch (err) {
      setError(err);
    }
  }, []);

  return render({ isError, onChange, onBlur, value: format(internalValue) });
};
```

Note that we get the "render" function from the normal `children` prop, and we pass it the stuff it needs. The internal state buffer is maintained but the value only flows to the outside via `setValue` if it parses. This is a nicer syntax for the old [Higher-Order Component (HOC)](https://acko.net/blog/model-view-catharsis/) approach to doing this same thing.

Tailwind is doing basically the same thing to wrap the underlying DOM element here with their enhanced functionality and styling, it's just that there is (as you've noticed) a lot more going on in their example because of the needs of a high-use production library codebase. Hopefully the simpler toy example above makes it clearer what's happening.

Even this approach is falling out of favor compared to custom hooks, one could easily imagine a variation on the above that does something like

```
const { onBlur, onChange, isError, currentValue } = useValidation({ value, setValue });
```

Comment: This was immensely helpful! Thanks very much Jared.